# Python - Find unique counts of words and letters using dictionaries and tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm currently trying to create a script that would allow me to run through the text contained in a file and count the number of words, distinct words, list out the top 10 most frequent words and counts, and sort the character frequency from most to least frequent.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
os.getcwd()
import string

path = ""
os.chdir(path)

#Prompt for user to input filename:
fname = input('Enter the filename: ')

try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except IOError:
    #Invalid filename error
    print('\n')
    print("Sorry, file can't be opened! Please check your spelling.")
    sys.exit()

#Initialize char counts and word counts dictionary
counts = {}
worddict = {}

#For character and word frequency count
for line in fhand:
        #Remove leading spaces
        line = line.strip()
        #Convert everything in the string to lowercase
        line = line.lower()
        #Take into account punctuation        
        line = line.translate(line.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        #Take into account white spaces
        line = line.translate(line.maketrans('', '', string.whitespace))
        #Take into account digits
        line = line.translate(line.maketrans('', '', string.digits))

        #Splitting line into words
        words = line.split(" ")

        for word in words:
            #Is the word already in the word dictionary?
            if word in worddict:
                #Increase by 1
                worddict[word] += 1
            else:
                #Add word to dictionary with count of 1 if not there already
                worddict[word] = 1

        #Character count
        for word in line:
            #Increase count by 1 if letter
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] += 1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1

#Initialize dictionaries
lst = []
countlst = []
freqlst = []

#Count up the number of letters
for ltrs, c in counts.items():
    lst.append((c,ltrs))
    countlst.append(c)

#Sum up the count
totalcount = sum(countlst)

#Calculate the frequency in each dictionary
for ec in countlst:
    efreq = (ec/totalcount) * 100
    freqlst.append(efreq)

#Sort lists by count and percentage frequency
freqlst.sort(reverse=True)
lst.sort(reverse=True)

#Print out word counts
for key in list(worddict.keys()):
    print(key, ":", worddict[key])

#Print out all letters and counts:
for ltrs, c, in lst:
    print(c, '-', ltrs, '-', round(ltrs/totalcount*100, 2), '%')
```

When I run the script on something like romeo.txt:

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

I get this output:

```
butsoftwhatlightthroughyonderwindowbreaks : 1
itistheeastandjulietisthesun : 1
arisefairsunandkilltheenviousmoon : 1
whoisalreadysickandpalewithgrief : 1
i - 14 - 10.45 %
t - 12 - 8.96 %
e - 12 - 8.96 %
s - 11 - 8.21 %
a - 11 - 8.21 %
n - 9 - 6.72 %
h - 9 - 6.72 %
o - 8 - 5.97 %
r - 7 - 5.22 %
u - 6 - 4.48 %
l - 6 - 4.48 %
d - 6 - 4.48 %
w - 5 - 3.73 %
k - 3 - 2.24 %
g - 3 - 2.24 %
f - 3 - 2.24 %
y - 2 - 1.49 %
b - 2 - 1.49 %
v - 1 - 0.75 %
p - 1 - 0.75 %
m - 1 - 0.75 %
j - 1 - 0.75 %
c - 1 - 0.75 %
```

When I run the script on frequency.txt:

```
I am you you you you you I I I I you you you you I am
```

I get this output:

```
iamyouyouyouyouyouiiiiyouyouyouyouiam : 1
y - 9 - 24.32 %
u - 9 - 24.32 %
o - 9 - 24.32 %
i - 6 - 16.22 %
m - 2 - 5.41 %
a - 2 - 5.41 %
```

Could I get some guidance on how I could think about separating out the words on each line to be distinct, and counts summed up in the manner desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code removes spaces in order to split by space – that doesn't make sense. As you want to extract every word from a given text, I would suggest that you align all words next to each other with a single space inbetween – that means that you have to remove not only new lines, unnecessary spaces, special/undesired characters and digits, but control characters as well.

That should do the trick:

```
import sys
import os

os.getcwd()
import string

path = "/your/path"
os.chdir(path)

# Prompt for user to input filename:
fname = input("Enter the filename: ")

try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except IOError:
    # Invalid filename error
    print("\n")
    print("Sorry, file can't be opened! Please check your spelling.")
    sys.exit()

# Initialize char counts and word counts dictionary
counts = {}
worddict = {}

# create one liner with undesired characters removed
text = fhand.read().replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", "")
text = text.lower()
text = text.translate(text.maketrans("", "", string.digits))
text = text.translate(text.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))
text = " ".join(text.split())

words = text.split(" ")

for word in words:
    # Is the word already in the word dictionary?
    if word in worddict:
        # Increase by 1
        worddict[word] += 1
    else:
        # Add word to dictionary with count of 1 if not there already
        worddict[word] = 1

# Character count
for word in text:
    # Increase count by 1 if letter
    if word in counts:
        counts[word] += 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 1

# Initialize dictionaries
lst = []
countlst = []
freqlst = []

# Count up the number of letters
for ltrs, c in counts.items():
    # skip spaces
    if ltrs == " ":
        continue
    lst.append((c, ltrs))
    countlst.append(c)

# Sum up the count
totalcount = sum(countlst)

# Calculate the frequency in each dictionary
for ec in countlst:
    efreq = (ec / totalcount) * 100
    freqlst.append(efreq)

# Sort lists by count and percentage frequency
freqlst.sort(reverse=True)
lst.sort(reverse=True)

# Print out word counts sorted
for key in sorted(worddict.keys(), key=worddict.get, reverse=True)[:10]:
    print(key, ":", worddict[key])

# Print out all letters and counts:
for ltrs, c, in lst:
    print(c, "-", ltrs, "-", round(ltrs / totalcount * 100, 2), "%")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to modify it to get it to print out the word count properly. However, when I run a large text file through the script, it's picking up apostrophes in the character count. Any thoughts on how I could have it only count letters? Seems that the string.punctuation line should have done the trick...?

Comment: Would using a punctuation translator work? Something like this:
`punc_translator = str.maketrans({key:None for key in punctuation})`
`text = text.translate(punc_translator)`
`text = " ".join(text.split())`

It's still picking up the apostrophes though

Comment: You've everything in place – just remove the characters you want to be removed using the `translate` method `text = text.translate(text.maketrans("", "", ",!.?;:\"'\/"))` or regular expression `text = re.sub("[,!.?;:\"']", "", text)`

Comment: Thank you, was able to filter out those undesired characters!

Answer (score 2):

```
line = line.translate(line.maketrans('', '', string.whitespace))
```

You are removing all whitespaces in the line with this code. Remove it and it should work as you intend.